# Helping finding definition of binwidth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble interpreting what binwidth means in ggplot2 and I am looking for a more precise definition of what it means.

For example:

```
#this is example is taken from Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis
library(ggplot2)
qplot(percbelowpoverty, data = midwest,binwidth=1)
```

How do I interpret binwidth=1? What are its units? How does that relate to the number of bins that are calculated? I have no clue and I'm not finding ?stan_bin to be helpful in answering my question:

*binwidth

The width of the bins. Can be specified as a numeric value, or a function that calculates width from x. The default is to use bins bins that cover the range of the data. You should always override this value, exploring multiple widths to find the best to illustrate the stories in your data.
The bin width of a date variable is the number of days in each time; the bin width of a time variable is the number of seconds.*

Maybe just don't know where to look for documentation of things like this because I am having difficulty understanding a number of related issues (such as what the "weight" aesthetic is all about).

Comment: Well, use of `qplot` is discouraged be cause it's not easy to tell what's going on. You seem to be drawing a histogram so the relevant details are on the `?geom_histogram` help page. Histograms bin continuous data into groups and count the number of observations in each bin. Setting `binwidth=1` mean each bin should be one x unit wide, eg (1-2], (2-3], (3,4], etc. The units are whatever units the `midwest$percbelowpoverty` values are in.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've answered my own question.  I was having trouble because I misread the x-axis units.  The precentages  in the midwest$percwhite column are not actually percentages (i.e, 96.7 is meant by us to be interpreted as 96.7%, but as data it is the actual number 96.7). It was for this reason I was confused about how to interpret the binwidth argument.  Now I see that it has the standard interpretation that MrFlick provided in the comment:

*Setting binwidth=1 mean each bin should be one x unit wide, eg (1-2], (2-3], (3,4], etc. The units are whatever units the midwest$percbelowpoverty values are in.*